# How to create a function to add a new array to an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have data coming from the db and I want the user to be able to add a new array after adding the new changes. I want a function that can be used multiple times for different ajax calls.

My object array is var basinSub and the content of the object array is:

{BasinId: (array stuff), SubBasinId: (array stuff), SubBasinName: (array stuff)}

How can I create a for key in data function that I can add a new array to the basinSub object?

I was thinking something like this but it's not working:

```
function locationChangeData(value, desc) {
    for(var i in basinSub) {
        if(basinSub[i].value == value) {
            basinSub[i].desc = desc;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would call the function in the ajax success function:

```
locationChangeData(basinSub, newSubBasinToAddSub);
```

Which newSubBasinToAddSub is the new array to add to basinSub.

Comment: this might be of help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do it

```
    //function to add new changes
    function targetChange(target, source) {
        Object.keys(source).forEach(function(key) {
            for(i=0;i<source.length;i++) {
                target[key][target[key].length++] = source[key][i];
            }
        });
    }
```